# Having trouble editing array of pointers to structures outside of main

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I have a program here that will read a tab delimited text file and put the contents into their respective places in a structure: title, author, publisher, year, and isbn.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
  char *title;
  char *author;
  char *publisher;
  int *year;
  char *isbn;
}Book;

int numLines(FILE* fp) {
  int lines = 0;
  char buffer[1000];

  while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != NULL) {
    lines++;
  }
  return lines;
}

void searchBook(Book books[], int i, int input) {
  int x;

  for (x = 0; x < i; x++) {
    if (*books[x].year == input) {
    printf("%s \n", books[x].title);
    printf(" Author: %s\n", books[x].author);
    printf(" Publisher: %s\n", books[x].publisher);
    printf(" Year: %d\n", *books[x].year);
    printf(" ISBN: %s\n\n", books[x].isbn);
    }
  }
}

void createBook(Book books[], int i, int *count) {
  books = malloc(sizeof(Book));
  char buffer[1000];
  int s;

  printf("Enter a title: ");
  scanf("%s", buffer);
  s = strlen(buffer);
  books[i + 1].title = malloc(s * sizeof(char));
  strcpy(books[i + 1].title, buffer);

  printf("Enter a author: ");
  scanf("%s", buffer);
  s = strlen(buffer);
  books[i + 1].author = malloc(s * sizeof(char));
  strcpy(books[i + 1].author, buffer);

  printf("Enter a publisher: ");
  scanf("%s", buffer);
  s = strlen(buffer);
  books[i + 1].publisher = malloc(s * sizeof(char));
  strcpy(books[i + 1].publisher, buffer);

  printf("Enter a year: ");
  scanf("%s", buffer);
  s = atoi(buffer);
  books[i + 1].year = malloc(sizeof(int));
  *books[i + 1].year = s;

  printf("Enter a ISBN: ");
  scanf("%s", buffer);
  s = strlen(buffer);
  books[i + 1].isbn = malloc(s * sizeof(char));
  strcpy(books[i + 1].isbn, buffer);

  (*count)++;
}

int main(void) {
  FILE *fp;
  char buffer[1000], *token, *del = "\t";
  int i = 0, length, input;
  int count, x;

  fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
  count = numLines(fp);

  Book *books;
  books = malloc(count * sizeof(Book));

  fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");

  while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != NULL) {
    token = strtok(buffer, del);
    length = strlen(token) + 1;
    books[i].title = malloc(length * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(books[i].title, token);

    token = strtok(NULL, del);
    length = strlen(token) + 1;
    books[i].author = malloc(length * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(books[i].author, token);

    token = strtok(NULL, del);
    length = strlen(token) + 1;
    books[i].publisher = malloc(length * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(books[i].publisher, token);

    token = strtok(NULL, del);
    length = atoi(token);
    books[i].year = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *books[i].year = length;

    token = strtok(NULL, del);
    length = strlen(token);
    books[i].isbn = malloc(length * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(books[i].isbn, token);
  i++;
}
fclose(fp);

  createBook(books, i, &i);

  printf("%s\n", books[12].title);
  printf("%s\n", books[12].author);
  printf("%s\n", books[12].publisher);
  printf("%d\n", *books[12].year);
  printf("%s\n", books[12].isbn);
}
```

There were 11 lines in the original text file.

If I create a new "books" structure in main, then it works, however, if I do it outside of main in the createBook function, it doesn't work. How do I use my createBook function to make a new structure that I can access in main?

Comment: Standard mistake that many beginners make. In C function parameters are always pass by reference. So `books = malloc(sizeof(Book))` in the function does not do what you think it does. It assigns to a *local* variable `books` and does not affect the caller's `books` variable. You need to either pass in a pointer to a pointer or return the `books` variable from the function.

Comment: `s = strlen(buffer);` --> `s = strlen(buffer)+1;`

Comment: Doh, mistyped my comment. It should say: In C, function parameters are always pass **by value**.